# Can't load DotNetNuke (DNN) Install Wizard - .js,.css 404 errors

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, dotnetnuke

I'm attempting to install a fresh installation of DNN, to evaluate it as well as extend it with custom functionality. The end goal is to gain knowledge on how it behaves prior to receiving a DNN-based product from a third party developer. I've been stumped right from the outset, so am reaching out to the forum for some help.

## Problem Statement

**I am unable to install DNN at all**, because the installation wizard does not load properly, and is missing some controls. It doesn't load most external resources (.css, .js, etc), and inspecting the headers shows those resources are returning 404 errors. Notably, the browser continually (over 1000x) attempts to load **dnn_logo.png**, each time returning a 404. I would like to know how to install/configure the site source files so that the installation wizard works properly, and I can continue the installation process. I am using the "Installation Package" variant of the software.

## Problem Background

- I checked the path of **dnn_logo.png** and it does in fact exist.
- I've been using this guide to install the site: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/install_dotnetnuke (the 2nd section, with separate DB).
- My installation environment: Win7 x64, IIS 7.5; SQL Server Express, named instance, using windows auth
- DNN version: 7.3.1
- Installation folder permissions are:

  - IIS AppPool\DotNetNuke --> modify
  - NT Authority\Network Service --> modify
- SQL Permissions: both users above are set as db_owner for the database

## Attempted Resolution Steps

1. Followed the written tutorial, as well as four installation videos authored by the DNN team
2. Reinstalled the site three times - first was using outdated v.7.3, 2nd selected the "unblock" option when unzipping the source
3. Adjusted folder permissions and double checked them; for user DotNetNuke
4. Added user Network Service with permissions, according to the info in the linked doc
5. Adjusted web.config and turned off URL rewriting; ended up reverting all changes

Comment: If it's missing some files, it may have something to do with the ZIP file you used on the install.  Try Right-Click, Properties, UNBLOCK. Then, extract the files.  Sometimes, Windows will block certain files inside ZIP archives by default.

Comment: @L_7337 -- thx for the tip. I updated OP to add I tried that on reinstall 2.

Comment: If it's just a 404, can you view the folder at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solved

IIS 7.5 (and others) needs to have the **ASP.NET server extensions** installed, and this will fix the problem. To get you started: you can add these by either going to **Turn Windows Features On or Off** from the Start Menu of **Windows 7**, or by using the **Microsoft Web Platform Installer** from within IIS (if you've downloaded IIS separately).

The solution was in the developer docs located elsewhere on the DNN site, found here: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/development-environment .

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issues and thought I would share my solution for others that may need it.  It turned out that turning on IIS Management Service solved my issue.  To enable this feature go to turn windows features on or off as mentioned above. Select Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools & check IIS Management Service.